# Custom Email action in workflow using Sitecore cloud email

Tags: workflow

We are using Sitecore email cloud as our smtp server, we are trying to send custom email notification during publishing workflow. We are using below code to send mail and set SMTP to be sitecore.smtp.e.sparkpost.com as per https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/exm/34/email-experience-manager/use-the-sitecore-email-cloud-service.html but it does not work, any ideas ?

```
 var message = new MailMessage(from, to);
 message.Subject = subject;
 message.Body = body;
 new SmtpClient(host).Send(message);
```

Edited this is the error i got:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: Start by investigating is there any errors in log files. Check logs after email should be sent.

Comment: Also verify if there are any gateway/firewall rules blocking traffic to SMTP